# Organización secuencial indexada

Tags: java

Buenas primera vez en stack overflow:
Estoy aprendiendo a trabajar con ficheros, en especial la organización secuencial indexada de estos. Pero necesito que me aclaren el significado de lo señalado en la figura.
Se les agradece su colaboración.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No entiendo que son esas cosas en los dibujos. Podrias explicar mejor?

Comment: En la figura?? Pues hay un 3 con un circulo rojo, también un -1, luego otro 3... De verdad?? Con esta explicación crees que alguien va a poder entender tu pregunta??